# Condition formatting of cells in one range that do not equal cells in the same row of another range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set up a formula or rule (don't know which is the best to do this) in Excel 2010.

I have values in "D10:D80", which I parse daily from the web, in the format (￥ 15,792) and values in the same format in "O10:O80". I would like conditionally to format the entire "D" cell (to became red) if the price in the "O" column is different from the price in the corresponding row of Column "D".

Answer (score 0):

Please see below image, select the first cell to format then conditional formatting. 
I've added (badly draw) arrows on to the settings and the formula you need to use. this will work. after that copy the formatting down the page :)

[image: Example:]

[image: Edit:]

Comment: Hi Kdean571 thx for your reply , in your case I will color the "C"cell  , which is a third cell in your case , I would like to format condition one of the two "in my case "D" or "O" "respectively and not addition one

Comment: Hi, this should still work, so if you want to format D1 if its not equal to O1 then repeat the example above but change the columns to O and D :)

Comment: hi Kdean571  , no  it doesn't seems to be working if I copy down the formula to all the column  unfortunately for me :-(  do you have some other suggestion? THX

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, if you type the formula without the $ in then when you copy use the right click then paste formatting it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the range you want to format (ie D10:D80 - though entire ColumnD is possible is you wish) and HOME > Styles, - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$D10<>$O10
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> select your formatting (red), OK, OK.

Comment: hi probably my mistake I didn't explain clearly , I mean D10:D80 has to match with O10:O80 , if not matching the D10:D80 cell color red

Comment: yes exactly all the column D (D10:D80) has to match the column O (O10:O80 )cells  respectively and if the price are not matching  the D cell has to get red , D10<>O10 AND D11<>O11 AND D12<>O12....